# I need help with proving a summation with induction - mainly just help point me in the right direction please

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

For all integers $n \geq 0,$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i 2^i = n 2^{n+2} +2.$$

I'm not sure how to start this and how to get it going, I thought I would start with the base case and make $n=1$, but it doesn't make both sides equal to each other and with the induction step I am just not fully sure how to get it going. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

base case $n = 0$

$\sum_\limits{i=1}^1 i2^i = 2$

Suppose $\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n+1} i2^i = n2^{n+2} + 2$

We must show that $\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n+2} i2^i = (n+1)2^{n+3} + 2,$ using the assumption above.

$\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n+2} i2^i = \sum_\limits{i=1}^{n+1} i2^i + (n+2)2^{n+2}$

Next apply the assumption and use your algebra skills to show what you need to show.

$n2^{n+2} + 2 + (n+2)2^{n+2}$ by the inductive hypothesis.
$(2n+2)2^{n+2} + 2\\
2(n+1)2^{n+2} + 2\\
(n+1)2^{n+3} + 2$

Comment: after simplifying, I got to (n+1)(2^n+3 + 2 + 2^n+1), would that be fully simplified or can I do more? I'm not fully sure.

Comment: you are done when you have $(n+1)2^{n+3}+ 2$ on both sides.

Comment: Ok, so I get to 2^n+3 * n+ 2^n+4 + 2 + 2^n+2*n - that’s where I get stuck, how do I simplify this?

Comment: I don't know how you got that.  I have added my algebra.

Comment: I see how I somehow got that weird answer, I think I was looking at the problem and just trying to complicate it too much (as well as not taking a moment to properly think it out). Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For the case where $n = 1$ we have that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{2}i2^i = 2+2(2^2) = (1)2^{(1+2)}+2 = 10
$$
So the base case does hold (you should use $n=0$ as you write you must prove it for all $n\geq 0$.) You may have been forgetting that the LHS is a summation, and you must add the terms up to the corresponding $n+1$.
Now assume that the statement holds for some arbitrary $k \geq 0$ and try to show that this implies it holds for $k+1$.